# What is the largest Worklight payload in notificationData allowed?

Tags: javascript, json, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a worklight notification adapter - and the payload looks like this :

```
WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, {
        badge: 1,
        sound: "sound.mp3",
        activateButtonLabel: "ClickMe",
        alert: notificationText,
        payload: {
            valueOne : inp1,
            valueTwo : inp2,
            valueThree : inp3
        }
    });
```

An example of invoking this 2 times is below - message from messages.log:

[

```
3/11/13 23:37:52:595 GMT] 00000981 com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl                 W Failed to send message com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification@bb51701b... trying again
java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.k(qc.java:71)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.h.write(h.java:29)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:86)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:161)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:52)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection.sendNotification(ApplicationConnection.java:84)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.APNSMediator.sendNotification(APNSMediator.java:85)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.Mediator$4.run(Mediator.java:174)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:482)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1121)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:614)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)

[3/11/13 23:41:53:849 GMT] 00000bff com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl                 W Exception while waiting for error code
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:200)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:132)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:125)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:207)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:488)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.e.read(e.java:32)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:113)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl$1MonitoringThread.run(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:102)
```

Yet if i reduce my payload to just 2 values - it works. Is 2 some kind of limit?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limitation on the payload values size.
Does the SocketException happen to you consistently with more that 2 values?

Comment: From apple page: The maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 256 bytes. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)

Comment: Aha! So how best do I measure the current total payload size - because the apple payload includes badge, alert, etc + the WL payload itself - makes it quite difficult to calculate the complete payload size in worklight.

Comment: Currently worklight does not have size validations for the different mediators. You can open a feature request [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=461545&tstart=0)